# Bounds does not work for GMSAutocompleteFetcher in Google Place API in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, google-places-api, bounds

I made this autocomplete code for searching places. And search correctly but bounds and region not set. show places out of my bounds.

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
@import GooglePlaces;


@interface SearchViewController () <GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate,GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate>
@end
@implementation SearchViewController{
    UITextField *_textField;
    UITextView *_resultText;
    GMSAutocompleteFetcher* _fetcher;
    GMSPlacesClient *_placesClient;
    GMSCoordinateBounds *_bounds;
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *_filter;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //APIkEy
    [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBYA7KlOZ3VqjQTG4x0R1jaCt9I1-1EVBc"];
_placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
// Set bounds
    CLLocationCoordinate2D neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.818074, 51.586990);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.557071, 51.098099);
    _bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:neBoundsCorner coordinate:swBoundsCorner];
// Set up the autocomplete filter.
    _filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    _filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter;
// Create the fetcher.
    _fetcher = [[GMSAutocompleteFetcher alloc] initWithBounds:_bounds filter:_filter];

    _fetcher.delegate = self;
// Set up the UITextField and UITextView.
    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 5.0f, 44.0f)];
    _textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    _resultText =[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 1.0f)];
    _resultText.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95f alpha:1.0f];
    _resultText.text = @"No Results";
    _resultText.editable = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:_textField];
    [self.view addSubview:_resultText];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    [_fetcher sourceTextHasChanged:textField.text];
}
#pragma mark - GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate
- (void)didAutocompleteWithPredictions:(NSArray *)predictions {
    NSMutableString *resultsStr = [NSMutableString string];



    for (GMSAutocompletePrediction *prediction in predictions) {
        [resultsStr appendFormat:@"%@\n", [prediction.attributedPrimaryText string]];
        NSLog(@"sec is: %@",[prediction.attributedSecondaryText string]);
        NSLog(@"placeID is: %@", prediction.placeID );


        [_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:prediction.placeID callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Place Details error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            if (place != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
                NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
                NSLog(@"Place placeID %@", place.placeID);
                NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
                NSLog(@"Place latitude %f", place.coordinate.latitude);
                NSLog(@"Place longitude %f", place.coordinate.longitude);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No place details for %@", prediction.placeID);
            }
        }];





    }
_resultText.text = resultsStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the bounds only [biases results to that rectangle](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_fetcher#member-function-documentation), it isn't a strict restrict.